# Provide tracking_url for products which have the 'Require a shipping address' option disabled

Tags: shopify

I would like to setup the products/variants not to require a shipping address and I would like to use the shipping notification email to notify the users and sent them their download url (as the products are digitally distributed).

Right now it looks like I cannot specify a tracking_url for variants where the 'Require a shipping address' is disabled. Is this the intended behaviour or is there another way?

This is the code I have right now:

```
f = ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment.new
f.prefix_options[:order_id] = <shopify order id>
f.tracking_number = <some number>
f.tracking_url = <url>
f.notify_customer = true
f.line_items = ids
f.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: From the original question: "Is this the intended behaviour or is there another way?".

Comment: The point I want to make is that you can 'ship'/deliver digital goods to someone, therefore you don't need a shipping address, only the email address. A way of tracking this fulfilment from within Shopify is preferable because of the shipping notifications it can sent out.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'll pass it on as a feature request.